# Is it okay to use a proper name + verb+ing without "is"?

Tags: grammar

I've seen a lot of YouTube titles or article titles without "is" before a verb + "ing". For example: "Gordon going insane" or "Gordon losing his temper." Is it a grammatical error or is it okay with proper names or something like that?

Comment: What you have with your examples are effectively just adjectival clauses describing their subjects (which are ***YouTube videos***, not ***Gordon***). They're not complete sentences, so there's no real meaning to asking whether they're "grammatical". Essentially this is the same as many previous questions asking about the "grammar" of "headlinese" in newspapers.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers ... Is it OK? Yes!  Titles need not be sentences.

Comment: 'Napoleon Crossing The Alps' ... Jacques-Louis David ... 1801 // It's far more common with particular rather than generic contexts ('Man bites dog', nearer a sentence, is the closest fixed expression I can think of that uses non-specifying nouns) and hence when a proper noun or two is/are involved.

Comment: @GEdgar: The problem is that although "Titles need not be sentences", they are syntactically constrained. So OP's examples could certainly feature Simple Present *Gordon **goes** insane / Gordon **loses** his temper*, or (much less likely, but still "valid") Simple Past *Gordon **went** insane / **lost** his temper*. But native speakers would never accept an infinitive (marked or unmarked) in such contexts, so it's not unreasonable to say that *Gordon **to go** insane* and *Gordon **lose** his temper* are actually ungrammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: this ideas that only complete sentences can be ungrammatical bothers me. I'd say that "Gordon going insane" is perfectly grammatical, but "Gordon insanity going" is ungrammatical (even though you could probably guess the meaning).

Comment: Peter is correct. Grammaticality is recursive. Words, phrases, clauses, sentences all have grammatical rules. If a phrase or clause doesn't belong to a sentence, the only rules that don't matter are sentence rules. It may also be the case that phrases standing alone are considered part of an implicit full sentence whose other parts are elided for convenience. For video titles, that would be something like "[This video shows] Gordon going insane."

Comment: @Peter Shor It's a matter of definition of the term, of course. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality#:~:text=The%20notion%20of%20grammaticality%20rose,%2Dformed%2C%20grammatical%2C%20sentences.&text=This%20allows%20us%20to%20accurately,is%20a%20completely%20novel%20sentence.) has 'The notion of grammaticality rose alongside the theory of generative grammar, the goal of which is to formulate rules that define well-formed, grammatical, sentences.' And the article concentrates arguably solely on the sentence level. // Nordquist states that 'fragments ...

Comment: are usually treated as grammatical errors' [even though](https://www.thoughtco.com/sentence-fragment-1692088) 'they are commonly used by professional writers to create emphasis or other stylistic effects'. Acceptable but ungrammatical!? Unlike 'Colorless bright green temperatures usually snore when drinking Rioja', grammatical but rubbish/unacceptable.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, that's effectively the point I was making in my ***second*** comment. But I'm guessing that almost all the people who ask here on ELU whether some particular "context-specific sentence fragment" (product label, newspaper headline, whatever) is "grammatical" are actually non-native speakers who don't really understand the difference between "grammatically correct **sentence**" and "syntactically acceptable **utterance**". I didn't closevote myself here, but those that *did* eventually direct OP to a question about **Why to use page-level permissions**, which is hardly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, a YouTube title and an article title are two different cases. The article "title" is a headline, and something like "Boris Johnson losing the support of Parliament" is simply "[headlinese](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921)": an "is" is understood and deleted. The YouTube cases are different, and as visual artifacts, their titles parallel the way works of visual art like paintings have been titled for centuries: "Dogs Playing Poker" is not understood to have a deleted "are." Rather, it's understood as a descriptive phrase stating the content of the image. As siride suggested, if there's any imaginary sentence, it might be along the lines of "*This painting shows* dogs playing poker."

Comment: 'This is not dogs playing poker.' Not by Magritte.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly good noun phrase

Noun phrases are commonly used as titles, for example "The Lord of the Rings", "The Importance of Being Earnest", "Death in Venice". Specific works that follow the pattern you are asking about include "Men Behaving Badly" and "Being John Malkovich".

There is nothing special about the user of proper names.

Examples of the noun phrase used in a sentence include:

> The result of this would be Gordon going insane.

> I saw Gordon losing his temper.